# CollatorProvider mechanism has no effect on Collator

Tags: java, collation, spi

I have written a CollatorProvider that adds a rule for respecting whitespaces when ordering user names. I.e: "Martin Perez" goes before that "Martinez Perez".

```
public class MyCollatorProvider extends CollatorProvider
{
    @Override
    public Locale[] getAvailableLocales() {
        return new Locale[] {
            new Locale("en"),
            new Locale("es","ES"),
            new Locale("es"),
            new Locale("fr","FR"),
            new Locale("eu"),
            new Locale("en","EN")
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Collator getInstance(Locale locale)
    {
        RuleBasedCollator rbc = (RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance();        

        // Order names and surnames respecting white spaces
        // add more rules here ....
        final String rules = rbc.getRules().replaceAll("<'\u005f'", "<' '<'\u005f'");

        try
        {
            return new RuleBasedCollator(rules);
        }
        catch (ParseException pe)
        {
            throw new Error(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed the mechanism described in this page:https://blogs.oracle.com/kah/entry/user_defined_collation_in_apache

However, I deploy the jar in jre/lib/ext but it has no effect over Collator, which still has the old behaviour.

I know that JRE loads the CollatorProvider because if I change the classname in the service file an exception is thrown.

My local code to test Collator is:

```
import java.text.Collator;

public class TestCollator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Compare two strings in the default locale
        Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance();

        if( myCollator.compare("Martin Perez", "Martinez Perez") < 0 )
            System.out.println("Martin Perez va antes que Martinez Perez.");
        else
            System.out.println("Martinez Perez va antes que Martin Perez.");
    }
}
```

I am really stuck with this issue. Please, could somebody help me?